# Preimage of $0$ is submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

For $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, consider the map 
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{a,b} : &\mathbb{R}^2 &\longrightarrow \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathbb{R} \\
&(x,y) &\mapsto x^3 - (ax + b) - y^2
\end{eqnarray*}

I'm trying to find out for which values of $a$ and $b$, $S_{a,b} := f_{a,b}^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a $k$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$. This demands that for every point $p = (p_1, p_2) \in S_{a,b}$ there exist a $U_p \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ with $p \in U_p$ which is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and a differentiable map $f_p : U_p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2-k}$, such that $$f_p^{-1}(\{0\}) = U_p \cap S_{a,b} 
\,\,\, \wedge \,\, \text{rk} f'(p) = 2-k.$$

Now if we take, for every $p \in S_{a,b}$, $U_p = \mathbb{R}^2$, then this significantly simplifies this. Namely, we can then simply take $k=1$ and $f_p = f_{a,b}|_{U_p}$, so that the first condition ($f_p^{-1}(\{0\}) = U_p \cap S_{a,b} 
$) is immediately satisfied. That leaves the second condition. Note that:

$$1 = \text{rk} f'(p) = \text{rk} [3p_1^2 -a \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, -2p_2] = \text{dim sp}\{3p_1^2 -a, -2p_2\}.
$$

The problem is that I don't see why this would not be the case for any $a,b$... Regardless the value of $a$ for example, we can still multiply $-2p_2$ by all real numbers to obtain the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ (unless $p_2 = 0$).

Comment: You have no choice but to take $k=1$, since you are given a map to $\Bbb R$, if you're trying to apply the Regular Value Theorem. The question is this: Can there be a point $(x,y)$ with $f_{a,b}(x,y) = 0$ for which $3x^2-a=-2y=0$? So, if $a\ge 0$, does the point $(\pm\sqrt{a/3},0)$ lie on that level set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a calculation, followed by an application of the regular level set theorem. You have

$f_{a,b}(x,y)= x^3 - (ax + b) - y^2,\ \partial f_x(x,y)=3x^2-a$ and $\partial f_y(x,y)=-2y.$

First, suppose $a\ge0.$ Then, the critical points for $f$ are $\left(\pm\sqrt{\frac{a}{3}},0\right)$. Now, substitute these points into $f$ and set to $0.$

$\left(\pm\sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}\right)^3-a\left(\pm\sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}\right)-b=0.$ from which $b=\mp 2\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}\right)^3.$

Thus, on the complement of  the set defined by the above equation, $f_{a,b}^{-1}(0)$ is a submanifold, (trivially) of rank $1$.

If $a<0$, there are no critical points, so $f_{a,b}^{-1}(0)$ is a submanifold for any value of $b$.

Comment: Sometimes it's better teaching to let the OP work with the hints/questions already there ... than to post a complete solution to earn rep.

Comment: Yes, maybe. But you are wrong about the "earn reps" remark, Made me chuckle though. There is so much snark and downvoting on this site that I guess a lot of you pay a lot of attention to that sort of thing. Anyway, [I often comment with hints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370036/how-to-compute-the-norm-of-the-linear-map-phi-mathcal-c00-1-mathbb-r-t), instead of answering, but in the case of differential geometry, I work through these things "out loud" because I am self-studying the subject myself.

Comment: Chuckle as you wish, but I've spent 6 or more years trying to teach here in a Socratic manner, and it is increasingly a losing battle. You've sabotaged my efforts a number of times. I should probably just quit.

Comment: Fair enough. I certainly did not intend to cramp your style. How can I tell when it's appropriate to answer? I notice that most questions get full answers, unless the OP specifically asks for hints only. In any case, when you have read this, let me know and I will gladly delete my answer.

Comment: @TedShifrin you'll be happy to know that I did not hand it in. I do want to thank Matematleta though, for his clear answer.