# How to compute the norm of the linear map $\phi:\mathcal C^0([0,1],\mathbb R) \to \mathcal C^1([0,1],\mathbb R)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

I'm doing this exercise in a lecture about linear maps between Banach spaces.

> **Exercise 16.**<sup>[(src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uIvz.png)</sup> Let $E=C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ with $\|f\|_{\infty}$. Let $\phi$ defined as
> $$\phi(f)(x) = \int_{0}^{x} tf(t) \, \mathrm{d}t. $$
>
> 1. Show that $\phi$ is continuous.
> 2. Compute the norm of $\phi$.

While I'm able to do (1), I unable to compute the norm of $\phi$, which is $\|\phi\|$.

**My questions:**

1. Could you please verify if my proof on (1) looks fine or contains logical gaps/errors?
2. Please shed me some light so compute $\|\phi\|$!

Thank you so much for your help!

---

**My attempt:**

1. By *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus*, $(\phi(f))'(x) = xf(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and thus $\phi(f) \in \mathcal C^1([0,1],\mathbb R)$. It is easy to verify that $\phi:\mathcal C^0([0,1],\mathbb R) \to \mathcal C^1([0,1],\mathbb R)$ is a linear map.

We have $$\begin{aligned} \|\phi(f)\|_\infty &= \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \left| \int_0^x t f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right| &&\le \sup_{x \in [0,1]}  \int_0^x |t f(t)| \, \mathrm{d}t \\ &\le \sup_{x \in [0,1]}  \int_0^x |f(t)| \, \mathrm{d}t && \le  \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \left (x \sup_{z \in [0,1]}|f(z)| \right) \\ &= \left (\sup_{z \in [0,1]}|f(z)|\right) \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \left (x  \right) &&=\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)| \\ &= \|f\|_\infty\end{aligned}$$

As such, $$\|\phi\| = \sup_{f \in \mathcal C^0([0,1],\mathbb R)} \dfrac{\|\phi(f)\|_\infty}{\|f\|_\infty} \le  \sup_{f \in \mathcal C^0([0,1],\mathbb R)} (1) =1$$

Since $\phi$ is a linear map and $\|\phi\| < \infty$, $\phi$ is continuous.

2. We have $$\|\phi(f)\|_\infty = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \left| \int_0^x t f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right| \quad \text{and} \quad \|f\|_\infty = \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)|$$

As such, $$\|\phi\| = \sup_{f \in \mathcal C^0([0,1],\mathbb R)} \dfrac{\|\phi(f)\|_\infty}{\|f\|_\infty} = \sup_{f \in \mathcal C^0([0,1],\mathbb R)} \dfrac{\sup_{x \in [0,1]} \left| \int_0^x t f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right|}{\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)|}$$

Comment: Where have you written down and computed the norm on $C^1([0,1],\Bbb R)$?

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin, you meant $$\|\phi(f)\|_\infty = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \left| \int_0^x t f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right|$$?

Comment: That is using the $C^0$ norm on that Banach space, not the $C^1$ norm. Forget your map $\phi$ for now. If I have a function $g$ in $C^1$, what is its norm?

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin, I thought that $C^1 \subseteq C^0$, so I use the $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ for $C^1$. I'm not sure if my approach is wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I'm just exposed to the subject and only use the norm $\| \cdot \|_\infty$. I don't know any other norm on this space.

Comment: Then they shouldn't have said you're mapping to $C^1$. You'd better check your course for a definition of a norm on that.

Comment: Thank you so much @TedShifrin, I will consult my professor about this point.

Comment: Your title does not necessarily match the actual question. First, $\mathcal{C}^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ is often assumed to be equipped with the norm $\|f\|=\|f\|_{\infty}+\|f'\|_{\infty}$, which is different from that on $\mathcal{C}^0([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. However, no such setting is mentioned in the actual question. Rather, what I only see is the space $E=\mathcal{C}^0([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, presumably intended to serve both the domain and codomain of the map $\phi$.

Comment: After the above comments, I also agree with you @SangchulLee. Now we have $$\phi:\mathcal C^0([0,1],\mathbb R) \to \mathcal C^0([0,1],\mathbb R)$$ Could you  pleasegive me some hints to finish (2)?

Comment: Hint: when you replaced $t$ by $1$ in the integral, you gave up too much.

Comment: The norm is clearly $\le 1/2.$ Can you find a function $f$ for which  $\|\phi(f)\|=1/2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that $\phi : E \to E$, where $E = C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ as mentioned in the original problem. First, for each $x \in [0, 1]$ we get

$$ \left| \int_{0}^{x} t f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right| \leq \int_{0}^{x} t \| f \|_{\infty} \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{x^2}{2}\|f\|_{\infty} \leq \frac{1}{2}\|f\|_{\infty}. $$

This shows that $\|\phi\| \leq \frac{1}{2}$. We claim that we actually have an equality here. To see this, note that

$$ \|\phi(1)\| = \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} \left| \int_{0}^{1} t \, \mathrm{d}t \right| = \sup_{x\in[0,1]} \frac{x^2}{2} = \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\|1\|_{\infty}, $$

and so, $\|\phi\| \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much :))))

Comment: @MadnessForMATH. Glad it helped.